# Using AWS Glue with Mysql in my EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-glue

I am trying to connect my ec2 installed/mysql with Glue, the purpose is to xtract some information and moved to redshift, but i am receiving the following error:

> Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

This is the format that i am using `jdbc:mysql://host:3306/database`

I am using the same vpc, same SG, same subnet for the instance.

i know the user/password are correct because i am connected to the database with sql developer.

What i need to check? Is it possible to use AWS Glue with mysql in my instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about the security groups involved? Can you update your question with security group details of EC2 and Glue connection ?

Comment: Also try giving IP address for host instead of dns name and try and update here what you see

Comment: To debug this you will need to specify the definition your security group attached to ec2 and glue. Yes it is possible to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the JDBC connection url that you have mentioned, use the private ip of the ec2 instance(where mysql is installed) as host.

> jdbc:mysql://ec2_instance_private_ip:3306/database

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to use AWS Glue with your MySQL running in your EC2 Instance but Before, you should first use [DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/dms/) to migrate your databases.

More over, your target database (Redshift) has a different schema than the source database (MySQL), that's what we call heterogeneous database migrations (the schema structure, data types, and database code of source databases are quite differents), you need [AWS SCT](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/dms/schema-conversion-tool/#:~:text=WQF%20uses%20AWS%20Schema%20Conversion,them%20to%20an%20AWS%20database.).

Check this out : [image]

As you can see, I'm not sure you can migrate straight from MySQL in an EC2 instance to Amazon Redshift.

Hope this helps